# hard time with JSON and google maps

Tags: json, google-maps

It might be a frequent question but i cannot figure out how to prevent errors in my parsing when the script can't find a property...

in XML was easy because even the empty properties were like `<location/>`

but now if `location` is not available JSON paser cant find it and it results in errors...OR

it may happen the json has different property or a children lost its father..... so for instance if you need to extract the `LocalityName` is no more under `SubAdministrativeArea` but under `AddressLine`...

any of you have any experience about? what the best way to solve it and to parse it correctly?

Comment: Post your code so we can see how you are currently trying to do this—then it's much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

While answering one of your other question I had written the following javascript code to obtain the lat and lng from the JSON returned by the maps api without any validations for zero results.

```
$.getJSON("getjson.php?address="+address,
        function(data){
            lat=data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            lng=data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                    //.....map initialization code      
       }    
    );
```

Now if I were to validate for zero results, I'd modify the code in the following way

```
$.getJSON("getjson.php?address="+address,
            function(data){
                if (data.result.length>0) {
                          for (count=0;count<data.result.length;count++){
                             lat=data.results[count].geometry.location.lat;
                             lng=data.results[count].geometry.location.lng;
                           //.....map initialization code       
                           }
                        }
                }   
        );
```

As you can see parsing JSON comes naturally to javascript and to many other languages for it resolves down to arrays/lists and objects/dictionary/hash.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right and you are using a library to convert to json like gson try to construct some kind of object array like arrayList in java and then convert to json so every object you retrieve later in javascript is distinct and thus clear during debugging.Also if you don't use firebug give it try as it shows json data clearly.cheers