# Google Geocode API result displaying on map?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm reading Google's API but see no examples there, and all the other Googled-by-me examples are a bit old (about 1-2 years old, most are API-key-based :S).

I want a text input. Send button. And Iframe below.

How to display location on the map using my own input?

At this moment my iframe looks like that:

```
<iframe width="230" height="180" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="<?php echo $src ?>">
```

Input:

```
<input id="googleMaps" name="googleMaps" type="text" />
```

At this moment I"m trying with XML (but JSON is recommended as far as I know?), but I'm getting XML just text in my iframe, like:

```
This document had no style information.
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>
OK
</status>
<result>
<type>
locality
</type>
<type>
political
</type>
<formatted_address>
(...)
```

How to pass this data to Google and get map back? :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the JavaScript API, since you want to display results on a map. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html There are examples for geocoding.

Comment: You didn't mention what kind of map you need, but you might find static maps easier to work with: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/. You'll be needing just a few basic tools: cURL and SimpleXML.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm going to display dynamic map (user types address like "blabla, New York, NY" and it displays a map with zooming options etc. Do I really need to use external scripts for that? ;s

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Google Geocode API to reverse geocode your address to obtain the co-ordinate which can then be used to display the results on the map. For example for my address I post to address parameters as given in the url below

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=154+Metro+Central+Heights+London+UK&sensor=true
```

Co-ordinates can be obtained from the resulting JSON as shown below

```
"geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 51.5001524,
        "lng": -0.1262362
      }
```

**PHP Code to obtain the JSON**

```
<?php

$address = $_GET['address'];
$address=str_replace(" ","+",$address);
if ($address) {
    $json = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.
    '&sensor=true');
    echo $json;
}

?>
```

The Javascript can be found [here](http://tallymobile.com/beam.js). The critical code which parses the JSON is given below

```
$.getJSON("getjson.php?address="+address,
        function(data){
            lat=data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            lng=data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                        //.... more map initialization code
                 }
);
```

I had already set up a working example for your previous question [here](http://tallymobile.com/test5.html) which should help you understand how to generate markers on the map. Let me know in case you need further clarification.

Comment: Ok, but what if I need to use XML instead of JSON? At this moment when I put "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" anywhere Opera popups download window and asks where to download this "json" file...

Comment: Each browser has a different way of handling different file formats. If you intend to see the JSON format try opening it in firefox or chrome. If you need XML you need to replace json with xml like this `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=your+address&sensor=true`. I've shown you the json format because it easier to parse this either using plain javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Again please note that in Safari, XML is rendered differently as opposed to say IE. If you need to see the raw XML document in Safari you need to view the source. Do not how it is with Opera.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said before vertyhing with xml works fine, but have no idea how to parse :(

Comment: I have written a note about parsing JSON here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979369/hard-time-with-json-and-google-maps/4239701#4239701

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. So how Google Maps work? If XML is parsed differently in every browser and JSON also so there's no easy way of making own implementation of GMaps API compatibile on major browsers? :O

Comment: You got me wrong. The browser may render the XML or JSON in different ways however you need to deal with them programmatically as I've done here either at the server (PHP in this case) and at the client with Javascript. Can you please take a look at my working example, try it out for yourself and let me know which part your unable to get your head around and I'll gladly assist.